# I have an "X" variable that contains data (A, B, C, D). and the variable "Y" is worth 10

Tags: java

I have an "X" variable that contains data (A, B, C, D). and the variable "Y" is worth 10. I want to do the looping of "X" a number of Y, but how to do iteration for the result is

> A B C D A B C D A B

```
package shiftkerja;

import java.util.Scanner;

/**
*
* @author USER
*/
public class ShiftKerja {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner jml = new Scanner(System.in);
    int[] deret = {0,1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34,55,89,144,233,377,};
    System.out.println("Masukan Jumlah Pekerja: ");
    Integer jumlah = jml.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Masukan Jumlah Hari: ");
    Integer hari = jml.nextInt();
   String[] pekerja = new String[jumlah];


        for (int i = 0; i < pekerja.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.println("Pekerja ke "+i+": ");
            pekerja[i] = jml.next();

        }
    System.out.println("-------------------------");

    for (int k = 0; k < deret.length; k++)
    {
    for (String p: pekerja){
        System.out.println(p+" akan bekerja selama: ");
    }    
    }
}
```

Comment: `Stream.generate(() -> x).flatMapToInt(Arrays::stream).limit(y).forEach(System.out::println);`

Answer (score 1):

Your program is not clear to the question asked but the solution for your 
example can be done like:

Assumtion x is array(X = [A,B,C,D]) and y is int.
Lets say xLen be holding length of the "X"

```
int i,j = 0,xLen = x.length;
for(i = 1; i < y; i++){
  j = j % xLen;
  System.out.println(x[j]);
}
```